# Deactivate Git pre-commit hook via command line

Tags: git

I'm using Git pre-commit/pre-push hook to build my software before every commit. This is, of course, useful when I change source code files. The hook also runs if I change non-source code files (e.g. `ReadMe.md`). For those commits, I don't want to run the hook.

Is there a way to deactivate the hook via the command line?

Comment: Could you submit your config files for the hook? Because there you could put a regex in order to only evaluate file types that you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a flag `-n` which stands for `--no-verify`, is very handy to bypass hooks on git commits

```
git commit -n
```

Comment: This would be a temporal solution, the better solution would be to modify the config files in order to only run the hook when certain ile types are change.

Comment: Indeed, fixing the pre-commit logic to exclude specific files will be the best solution